# Why does the rogue's Greater Weapon Specialization specify legendary proficiency?

Tags: rogue, pathfinder-2e, proficiency

The [rogue's](https://2e.aonprd.com/Classes.aspx?ID=10) level 15 class feature specifies:

> Your damage from weapon specialization increases to 4 with weapons and unarmed attacks in which you’re an expert, 6 if you’re a master, and 8 if you’re legendary.

How can a rogue get legendary proficiency in any weapon? As far as I'm aware, only the fighter reaches legendary proficiency with weaponry, but a fighter will never be able to qualify for this feature because it comes directly from the rogue's list of class features rather than a rogue feat. Consequently, the two states:

1. Has legendary proficiency
2. Has access to this feature

seem mutually exclusive. Is there something I've missed?

Comment: I can now see that this looks like a general feature applied to all non-spellcasting classes? So is this just an artefact of Paizo copy-pasting features between classes?

Comment: Theoretically it could also be futureproofing. Not sure if that's something they're doing for 2e or not.

Comment: Futureproofing is my guess.  If someday this is possible, there's no ambiguity as to whether Greater Weapon Specialization improves your damage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is currently no way for a rogue to reach legendary proficiency; it is a fighter thing, presently. That doesn't mean in the future there won't be an archetype or feat that would allow it. This is likely just future proofing.